# how to get first video after ending last video youtube api

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get first video after completing last video i am using youtube i will play video continues but after last video its ending its not getting first video here the code i am working  on

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script>
    /**
     * Put your video IDs in this array
     */
    var videoIDs = [
        'MCgODvsmrmY',
        'RdyXFNgZdCw'
    ];

    var player, currentVideoId = 0;


    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '768',
            width: '1026',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
        node.requestFullScreen();

document.fullScreen; 

    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            currentVideoId++;

            if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {

                player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onPlayerStateChange` function to reset `currentVideoId` to 0 when the last video is finished:

```
currentVideoId++;
if (currentVideoId >= videoIDs.length) {
    currentVideoId = 0; }

player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
```

Comment: can you add your code with full source by changing my code